# Animate the scattering of a Wave Packet

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, animation

I know mathematica is probably not the best choice for intense numerical integration, but its the only software I know.

I would like to create an animation (not real-time, but pre-render the frames) of a Gaussian wave-packet scattering against a spherical square-well, whose stationary states are known.  Basically, I need to carry out the following integral:

$$\Psi(\vec{x},t)=\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}}\tilde{f}(\mathbf{k}) \psi_\mathbf{k}(\vec{x})\,e^{-i E(\mathbf{k})t}$$

where $\tilde{f}(\mathbf{k})=\exp(-\frac{(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_0)^2}{2(\Delta k)^2}-i \mathbf{k}.\vec{x}_0)$ is the Gaussian wavepacket in Fourier space, and $E(\mathbf{k})$ is a very simple function quadratic in $\mathbf{k}$.

The integral needs to be done at several different times, and then compiled together to form an animation (this last step I know how to do).  Is there a good reference that I can look up that will accomplish my task?

Comment: Could you please post your animation's result as an answer when you're done?

Comment: Why do you think M- is "not the best choice for intense numerical integration" - do you have examples where it does not work well?

Comment: @ruebenko Agreed. I tried to address that issue in my response.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, and that's another nice answer from you!

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing much about quantum mechanics, there's a lot going on in your integral that I know nothing about.  The basic ideas are the same for any sequence of objects generated by numerically computed integrals, though.  Suppose, for example, you want to estimate
$$\iiint_{{\mathbb R}^3} e^{-\langle x,y,z \rangle \cdot \langle x,y,z \rangle / a} dV$$
for a range of $a$ values and the animate the results.  We could proceed as follows.

```
Monitor[
  results = Table[Check[
  {result = NIntegrate[Exp[-{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}/a],
     {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
     {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
     {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]},
  {result, "Uh-oh", a}], {a, 0.1, 10, 0.1}],
a]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {56.448363, Null} *)
```

There are a few things going on here.  The results might take a while, so I'm using `Monitor` to watch the progress.  Also, I'm using `Check` to check for errors and returning the parameter that yields the error.  Examining the results, it appears that the error couldn't be too bad.

```
ListPlot[First /@ results]
```

[image]

Using `Table`, as done here, pre-generates a list of results that can be used to generate a smooth animation with `ListAnimate` like so:

```
ListAnimate[First /@ results]
```

[image]

Of course, this just generates the results; you'd want a function that turns those results into pictures, whatever that is.

Also, more parameters get's trickier.  Four parameters varying smoothly could take a while but you can check.  Consider the following variation.

```
Monitor[
 results = Table[Check[
  {result = NIntegrate[Exp[-{x, y, z}.{x - x0, y - y0, z - z0}/a],
     {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
     {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
     {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]},
  {result, "Uh-oh", x0, y0, z0, a}],
 {x0, 0, 2, 1}, {y0, 0, 2, 1}, {z0, 0, 2, 1}, {a, 1, 5, 2}],
{x0, y0, z0, a}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {164.881392, Null} *)
```

Runs in 165s on my machine.  If I want to take the resolution of all 4 parameters down by the factor 10, it would take 10000 times as long - *only* three weeks.

I do think that it's hard to beat `NIntegrate`.  In addtion to automatically dealing with 3D improper integrals, here's a couple of integrals that `NIntegrate` just does:

```
NIntegrate[x^x^x, {x, 0, 6}]

(* Out: 1.102664999366306*10^36300 *)

NIntegrate[Sin[1/x]/x, {x, 0, 1}]

(* Out: 0.624713 *)
```

What other systems gets those so easily?

Comment: Wow, I really had no idea I could throw my function right in, and have it integrate in 3 dimensions.  I'll try it out!  Just a quick question.  The integrand is complex-valued.  Will that be a problem?

Comment: Complex values should be no problem.